# iTextSharp - Fit formatted Text to single page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a text file that is pre-formatted with spacing and line breaks.  I am writing the text out to a blank pdf that has been set to landscape with minimal margins to fit all the text to a single page, however I am still running off the page.  Can anyone recommend how I can use itextsharp to dynamically "fit to page" by reducing the font size and/or line-height (lead).  I have seen responses about using a textfield or rectangles but I can't seem to get those working properly.

Update:  Here is what I have so far that uses no advanced stuff at all, simply margin control and font size adjustments to force my sample text to the page.  This works fine if I always have fixed line lengths, but that unfortunately won't be the case.  There might be a common max line length I can use across the files but I don't have that data at this time.

```
private void CreatePDF()
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\dev\text1.txt");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string newFile = @"C:\dev\testPDF1.pdf";
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 50, 5, 5, 5);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
    pdfDoc.Open();
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    if (line != "\f")
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
    else
    {
        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(sb.ToString(), new Font(Font.NORMAL, 6)));
        pdfDoc.NewPage();
        pdfDoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
        pdfDoc.SetMargins(50, 5, 5, 5);
        sb.Clear();
        sb.AppendLine("");
    }
    }
    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(sb.ToString(), new Font(Font.NORMAL, 6)));
    pdfDoc.Close();
    //Console.Write(sb);            
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you've tried. This seems like a task for the `ColumnText` class, where you add the text in simulation mode to see if it fits a certain rectangle. If it does, you add the text for real; if it doesn't, you adapt the font and/or leading and try again in simulation mode. Etc...

Comment: I have updated post and added some code that I am currently with to create sample PDFs, sorry its not much to go on regarding my problem.  The one thing I notice when comparing the pdf I generate to the printed with PCL version is the line-height seems much tighter allowing for a larger font size to be used.  I am investigating the columntext approach as you mentioned.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie any further assistance you can provide after my update?

Comment: I don't see you using `ColumnText` in your update. I can't *fix* anything before you try.